# ASP.NET Core - Beginner Course - Database doesn't save changes on database when razor pages redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am doing the [Microsoft Virtual Academy Course](https://mva.microsoft.com/en-us/training-courses/asp-net-core-beginner-18153?l=9Sk7yj7dE_2111787171). I am at CRUD class.

[image: foreach file]
When the Create razor page redirect to indexModel page the DB has customers; so when the foreach try to get customers to show it's work, but when try to delete, it doesn't have customer to delete.
When I tried to delete a customer the webapplication throws a:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I debugged that and found the bug's root. The WebApp create a customer and redirect to IndexModel, IndexModel list the customers; but when I tried to delete a customer, the customers list on DB doesn't have no one customer. How you can see on screenshots.

[image: Create has the customer]

But IndexModel doesn't have Customers on DB.
[image: index doesn't have]

I don`t understand why db doesn't save the changes correctly; and I don't know how indexModel show a list of customers, even without customers on db. (the image above showing a step from debug,  I saw all the steps and in none moment has customers on IndexModel db).

I have search a lot on internet and used [Microsoft Virtual Academy Forum](https://trainingsupport.microsoft.com/en-us/tcmva/forum/all/nullreferenceexception-foreach-var-customer-in/23997bb8-c567-4438-942a-e845830f205d?rtAction=1540481936031), but I didn't fix it. Basically the bug is on foreach(theorically). Can you help me?

**The handler**

```
    [Route("delete/{id:int}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostDeleteASync(int? id)
    {
        // if (!ModelState.IsValid) return Page();
        var removeCustomer = await _db.Customers.FindAsync(id);
        if (removeCustomer != null)
        {
            _db.Customers.Remove(removeCustomer);
            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        return RedirectToPage("/index");
```

Comment: Can you provide the delete handler code please?

Comment: Already done! See it in the question.